# Free tool for Visual Testing / visual regression testing?

Tags: automated-testing

I have a localhost webapp (development) that requires a login to use and I would want to implement Visual Testing which for me means having a tool taking screenshots when I want and, as a plus, do the image diff.

The tool must be free and a big plus is if it's very easy to implement: I don't mind coding the test cases if needed but any kind of GUI would be a major plus. I also don't mind the tool requires to be installed on a server or anything like that.

It's not important to test on different resolutions/browsers, this is more about keeping 'stability' and knowing which pages changing than making sure everything is working OK visually. Something that uses Chrome to render the page is also nice.

Comment: Applitools has a free account with up to 100 visual checks (screenshots) a week. If that's enough checks for you, give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

**Vizzy:**

This is released recently by workday and was presented during one of the tech meetup:

https://github.com/Workday/vizzy

**silkulix**

http://sikulix.com/quickstart/

**Protractor-image-comparison**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison

**webdriver-image-comparison**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-image-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Adding Few more which I have used recently & are good for image pixel comparisions:

**1. PhantomCSS**

PhantomCSS takes screenshots captured by CasperJS and compares them to baseline images using Resemble.js to test for rgb pixel differences. PhantomCSS then generates image diffs to help you find the cause.

Refer:https://github.com/HuddleEng/PhantomCSS

**2. FBSnapshotTestCase (Uses XCTest):**

FBSnapshotTestCase uses a “snapshot test case” that takes a configured UIView or CALayer and uses the renderInContext: method to get an image snapshot of its contents. It compares this snapshot to a “reference image” stored in your source code repository and fails the test if the two images don't match.

Refer : https://github.com/facebookarchive/ios-snapshot-test-case

**3. Gemini (Uses JS DSL):**

Gemini is a utility for regression testing the visual appearance of web pages. Check it out on Getting Started with Gemini : http://www.kevinlamping.com/hands-on-visual-regression-testing/3-Gemini/1-install.html

**4. Needle (Uses Python):**

Needle is a tool for testing visuals with Selenium and nose.

It checks that visuals (CSS/fonts/images/SVG/etc.) render correctly by taking screenshots of portions of a website and comparing them against known good screenshots. It also provides tools for testing calculated CSS values and the position of HTML elements. See example in the Visual Regression Testingpost.

Refer : https://github.com/python-needle/needle